# How can I use an Apple remote control with customized actions without having the button actions happen?

Tags: remote-control, apple-remote-desktop, bettertouchtool

I want to use a white plastic Apple remote with BetterTouchTool to control Safari, but while it works, the default button actions (e.g. skip, volume up) still happen. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/)** will allow you do to this (plus a whole lot more if you wish). You can customise a range of actions for each application and assign these to the Apple remote buttons (this includes both press and press-and-hold). You can also define your own custom actions if the built-in ones don't suit. Nothing came close for me in terms of flexibility and ease of use - I tried both [Mira](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/) and [Sofa Control](http://www.caseapps.com/sofacontrol/) before settling on RB.

[image]

Personally, I use this to control my XBMC media centre with a range of custom button-presses and use the launch menu to start it up. It works with the white plastic remote too, I've just got the aluminium one thats shown in the screenshot.

Comment: To clarify: this overrides the button actions, rather than adding them?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder Thats right, it replaces the default actions with the new ones you assign for the particular application. But don't just take my word for it, I would download the trial version from the website and see if it does what you need.

Comment: There's also an "express" version [on the MAS](http://itunes.apple.com/app/remote-buddy-express/id438093690?mt=12&affId=2008573&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) which is a bit cheaper, if you don't need [remote support other than the Apple remote](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/compare/)

Comment: Hmm, $25 plus $15 for updates... per computer! I'd rather use Node Red and program my own solution.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I've been looking for a solution to this for a long time everywhere. That is discussions.apple.com, various popular technology websites and mac forums. The *only* real solution that I've seen is a piece of software by **Twisted Melon**.</sub>

### [Mira: Remote Control any Mac](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/)

This applications rests in the system preferences and **customizes the apple remote buttons on a per-app basis**. You can download and try the software from their website.

[image]

Comment: Any yes, it works in lion.

Comment: Isn't the software called Mira? I think its the hardware remote receiver thats the Manta bit.

Comment: @binarybob Thanks. I guess his was Autocorrect? Really strange typo... :)

Comment: The Mira page *is* a bit confusing, though. Near the top it does actually say "Manta: Remote control any Mac" and follows that with the Mira screenshot :-/

Comment: @binarybob Yeah. Manta is just the USB receiver.