# What software is available to customize the functionality of the Apple Remote?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, apple-remote-desktop

I am looking to change the functionality of the buttons on the Apple Remote. What software is available to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) can do this:

[image]

You can set up complex actions to be triggered by any of the buttons being either pressed or held.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I didn't know BTT would do that!!

Answer (score 3):

[Mira](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/) can customize the Apple Remote buttons on a per-app basis, and costs $16.

[Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) allows you to customize the Apple Remote and many other devices, however it does cost more than Mira.

[Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/) also allows you to customize the actions of an Apple Remote, as well as trackpad/mouse, but there seems to be issues with the default action still firing with BetterTouchTool ([see this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43246/how-can-i-use-an-apple-remote-control-with-customized-actions-without-having-the)). It is free though.

Comment: [Remote Buddy Express](http://itunes.apple.com/app/remote-buddy-express/id438093690?mt=12&affId=2008573&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) is also available for $20. A bit cheaper than the full version and only really differs in the fact that it doesn't provide control for devices other than the Apple remote. Its the best of the bunch, IMHO.

Comment: Hmm, binarybob and penguinrob.

Comment: We are in no way associated (that I know of) :-)